# declaration error while getting udp throughput in ns-3

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

in this ns-3 example (first.cc) i entered some lines of codes from other example for udp connection(copied between slashes) to calculate throughput of a udp connection, i checked and defined the newly added variables, and after running i get this error:

‘serverApp’ was not declared in this scope
   uint32_t totalPacketsThrough = DynamicCast (serverApp.Get (1))->GetReceived ();

```
#include "ns3/core-module.h"
#include "ns3/network-module.h"
#include "ns3/internet-module.h"
#include "ns3/point-to-point-module.h"
#include "ns3/applications-module.h"

using namespace ns3;

NS_LOG_COMPONENT_DEFINE ("FirstScriptExample");

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  Time::SetResolution (Time::NS);
  LogComponentEnable ("UdpEchoClientApplication", LOG_LEVEL_INFO);
  LogComponentEnable ("UdpEchoServerApplication", LOG_LEVEL_INFO);

  NodeContainer nodes;
  nodes.Create (2);

  PointToPointHelper pointToPoint;
  pointToPoint.SetDeviceAttribute ("DataRate", StringValue ("1000Mbps"));
  pointToPoint.SetChannelAttribute ("Delay", StringValue ("2ms"));

  NetDeviceContainer devices;
  devices = pointToPoint.Install (nodes);

  InternetStackHelper stack;
  stack.Install (nodes);

  Ipv4AddressHelper address;
  address.SetBase ("10.1.1.0", "255.255.255.0");

  Ipv4InterfaceContainer interfaces = address.Assign (devices);

  UdpEchoServerHelper echoServer (9);

  ApplicationContainer serverApps = echoServer.Install (nodes.Get (1));
  serverApps.Start (Seconds (1.0));
  serverApps.Stop (Seconds (10.0));

  UdpEchoClientHelper echoClient (interfaces.GetAddress (1), 9);
  echoClient.SetAttribute ("MaxPackets", UintegerValue (1));
  echoClient.SetAttribute ("Interval", TimeValue (Seconds (1.0)));
  echoClient.SetAttribute ("PacketSize", UintegerValue (1024));

  ApplicationContainer clientApps = echoClient.Install (nodes.Get (0));
  clientApps.Start (Seconds (2.0));
  clientApps.Stop (Seconds (10.0));
  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  uint32_t payloadSize = 1472; //1500 byte IP packet
  double simulationTime = 10; //seconds
  double throughput = 0;
  uint32_t totalPacketsThrough = DynamicCast<UdpServer> (serverApp.Get      (1))->GetReceived ();
  throughput = totalPacketsThrough * payloadSize * 8 / (simulationTime *     1000000.0); //Mbit/s
  std::cout << " *throughput = " << throughput ;                     

 /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
   Simulator::Run ();
   Simulator::Destroy ();
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm thinking your error is that you have declared `serverApps` not `serverApp`.

Comment: lol...that was right but now i don't get any results but this:

Comment: Waf: Entering directory `/home/hamid/workspace/ns-allinone-3.25/ns-3.25/build'
Waf: Leaving directory `/home/hamid/workspace/ns-allinone-3.25/ns-3.25/build'
Build commands will be stored in build/compile_commands.json
'build' finished successfully (1.496s)
Command ['/home/hamid/workspace/ns-allinone-3.25/ns-3.25/build/scratch/first'] terminated with signal SIGSEGV. Run it under a debugger to get more information (./waf --run <program> --command-template="gdb --args %s <args>").